# errors.full_messages no retorna ningun error ha pesar de haberlo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy comenzando en ruby on rails(7.0.2.3) and decidí crear un modelo llamado 'Article' así

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :body
      t.integer :visits_count
      t.timestamps
    end       
  end 
end
```

y las validaciones del modelo son estas

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
    validates :title, presence: true, uniqueness:true
    validates :body, presence: true, length:{minimum:20}  
end
```

Pero cuando dejo vacio los recuadros del formulario aproposito para que me devuelva los mensajes de error, esto no devuelve ninguno, el array formado por errors.full_messages.each queda vacio

FORMULARIO:

```
<div class="">
     <div class="">
         
         <div class="container" style="margin:0 auto;">
             <h1> <%= name %> articulo</h1>
             <%=form_for(@article) do |f|%>
                 <%= @article.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                     <div class="be-red white top-space">
                         * <%= "#{message}" %>
                     </div>
                 <%end%>
                 <div class="form-control">
                     <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder:"Aqui va el titulo", class:"form-control"%>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-control">
                     <%= f.text_area :body, placeholder:"Aqui va el texto del contenido", style:"height:200px",class:"form-control"%>
                 </div>
                 <div class="btn btn-sm", style="float:left" >
                     <%= f.submit "Enviar", class:"btn btn-sm be-red white", style:"padding:8px 10px" %>
                 </div>
             <% end %>
         </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Hi! This is Stackoverflow in spanish. Only questions in Spanish are accepted here.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu error está en

```
<%= @article.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
```

debería ser

```
<% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
```

Comment: Gracias por leer mi problema. Ese "=" que he colocado fue apropósito ya que este signo permite que pueda ver el array de errores. No afecta el resultado si lo pongo o no.